# Why can't my JSON file be found using require_relative from another file?

Tags: json, ruby

*I am new to Ruby and programming and am building my first terminal application. Any help is greatly appreciated.*

Why does the app crash at `rescue` when I call it from `main.rb` but can locate and write to log.json when I run the app from  `json.rb` ?

Specifically, I am having trouble **locating my log.json file** when running the app.

The app runs by calling a method from my `main.rb` file, located in the root directory.

I am trying to access my JSON file named `log.json`, located in the `methods` directory.

When I include `require_relative 'methods/json.rb` in my `main.rb` file, my app crashes producing:

```
/src/methods/log.json (LoadError)
    from main.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Alternatively, if I run the app from my file json.rb which writes to log.json
the app does not crash and the input is successfully added to log.json

```
require 'json'
require 'colorize'

class NotValidJsonError < StandardError
end

class FileNotFoundError < StandardError
end


# WRITE TO JSON FILE
def write_json_file(username)

    #ERROR HANDLING
    # file_path = './log.json'
    
    begin

        # file = File.read(file_path)

      file =  File.read(File.expand_path( "log.json", __dir__))

    rescue => e
        raise FileNotFoundError,"Could not find file"
        puts e.message
        puts e.backtrace.inspect
    end

    begin 

        json = JSON.parse(file)

    rescue => e
        raise NotValidJsonError,"Input is not valid Json "
        puts e.message
        puts e.backtrace.inspect
    end

    log_hash = Hash.new 


    log_hash["name"] = username

    puts "Which Level did you practice today?".colorize(:blue)
    log_hash ["Level"] = gets.chomp
    puts "What Key Signature did you practice?".colorize(:cyan)
    log_hash ["Key"] = gets.chomp


    json.push(log_hash)

    File.open('./log.json', 'w') do |f|
        f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(json)
    end

  
end



# WRITE TO JSON FILE
def read_json_file(username)

    #ERROR HANDLING

    file = File.read('./log.json')

    json = JSON.parse(file)

    json.each do |hash| 
        if hash["Name"] == username 
            puts "Your Level is #{hash["Level"]} and Key #{hash["Key"]} is"
        end
    end

end
```

Here is my main.rb code

```
#Relative methods

require_relative 'methods/welcome_page.rb'
require_relative 'methods/username_prompt'
require_relative 'methods/prompt_one.rb'
require_relative 'methods/challenge_selection.rb'
require_relative 'methods/key_signature_selection.rb'
require_relative 'methods/level_plus_key_calculator.rb'
require_relative 'methods/displayed_progression.rb'
require_relative 'methods/json.rb'


#Relative classes
require_relative 'classes/chord_progression'


#run program
username_prompt
```

Comment: If the error is coming from main.rb, including the relevant portion of main.rb would help. Your issue might be related to how, in Ruby, file operations with relative paths are going to be evaluated relative to the directory you launched Ruby from (and not, as you might think, relative to the Ruby file you're in). The way around that is typically to do `File.read(File.expand_path( "log.json", __dir__))`, which grabs the directory the Ruby file you're inside is located in as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert for your feedback and your help. After implementing your suggestion `File.read(File.expand_path( "log.json", __dir__)) ` the app now works

Comment: Although it does still seem to be erroring at `rescue`

Comment: `/methods/json.rb:32:in rescue in write_json_file: Input is not valid Json`

Comment: What are the contents of log.json? If it's empty, that's going to be invalid JSON since a proper JSON document (as they're called) needs at least one byte. Try editing it to be just opening and closing brackets: `{}`.

Comment: Thank you Robert very much Robert, That helped and it is now valid JSON! Do you mind sharing how I could add new data and populate `log.json` without overwriting the data that has already been parsed?

Comment: I found out how to do this. I needed to change the 'w' to an 'a' File.open('./log.json', 'a') do |f|
        f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(json)
    end